# MySQL Databases with Amazon

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

So I've recently started working with a client that has a Wordpress site run totally off Amazon Cloud Services. As part of some new work I'm doing for them, I need to directly access the database.

I looked at the most recent bill, and the charges I see from amazon are for:

Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud

Amazon CloudFront

AWS Data Transfer

Amazon Simple Storage Service

Amazon SimpleDB (however the charge is $0.00)

I see no charges for RDS or for another database service they provide, however, the wp-config lists localhost as the connection info.

So my question is, is there a way to setup a MySQL database on one of these services? I'm thinking no, and it's possible the database is on another account?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Elastic Compute Cloud (ec2). AWS does over an RDS service for a managed MySQL option, but you don't have to host it that way. Currently it appears MySQL is hosted on the same instance as WordPress is installed on.

Comment: Thanks for your help! You put me in the right direction and I found the phpMyAdmin for it!